# Ruby on Rails getting translation fields using model methods in render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a RoR API with this logic:

**Boat Controller**

```
def index

  Lot of stuff...
  @boats = query...

  render :json => @boats, :include => {:port => {:only => [:id, :name], :include => {:city => {:only => [:id, :name], :include => {:province => {:only => [:id, :name]}}}}}}
end
```

**Boat Model**

```
belongs_to :port
```

**Port Model**

```
belongs_to :city
```

and so on.

In the BoatController.index instead of city, I would like to return the city translated (for internationalization purposes). I won´t get into the details on the database relationship (just let me know if you need it). Anyway, I have a service that gets a city translated using a language and cityId parameters.
So, I would like to do something like:

**Boat Controller:**

```
render :json => @boats, :include => {:port => {:only => [:id, :name], :include => {:translatedCity => [:name], :city => {:only => [:id, :name], :include => {:province => {:only => [:id, :name]}}}}}}
```

**Port model**

```
def translatedCity 

    TranslationService.translateCity(self.city_id, lang)
end

belongs_to :city
```

This is the service method:

```
def self.translateCity(cityId, lang)

      city = Translation.find_by_sql(["SELECT t.element_translation
                                       FROM translations t, element_types et, languages l, cities c, states s
                                       WHERE et.name = 'City'
                                       AND l.locale = ?
                                       AND c.id = ?
                                       AND t.element_type_id = et.id
                                       AND t.language_id = l.id
                                       AND s.id = c.state_id
                                       AND c.id = t.element_id", lang, cityId]).first
      puts "translateCity.city:" + city.inspect
      return city
    end
```

The query is working and if I inspect the result I get something like:

```
translatedCity.city=#<Translation id: nil, element_translation: "Palma de Mallorca">
```

however I´m getting this error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
  app/models/boat.rb:29:in `as_json'
  app/controllers/boats_controller.rb:253:in `index'
```

I don´t know if it´s clear what I´m trying to do. Otherwise, let me know and I´ll clarify it.

Comment: I would add a `has_many :translations, as: :resource` to City. And a `belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true` to Translation. That way you can simply query `city.translations.find_by(language: 'de')`.

Comment: A lot less complicated and the query will be a lot faster provided that you create an index on `translations.resource_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your translation setup is overly complicated. You could simplify and speed the lookup of translation by adding a column to `translations` which links it directly to the entity it translates.

```
class AddResourceToTranslation < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :translations, :entity, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations, as: :entity
end

class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entity, polymorphic: true
end
```

---

```
> london = City.create
> london.translations.create(element_translation: 'Londres', language: 'fr', locale: 'fr')
> london.translations.where(language: 'fr').uniq.pluck('element_translation').first
=> "Londres"
```

Results in this sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT element_translation 
FROM "translations" 
WHERE "translations"."entity_id" = ? AND "translations"."entity_type" = ? 
    AND "translations"."language" = 'fr'  [["entity_id", 1], ["entity_type", "City"]]
```

## Addition

Provided that you [set the locale via I18n.locale](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) you could do:

```
class TranslationService
  # ...
    def translateCity(city, locale = I18n.locale)
        city.translations.where(locale: locale).pluck(:element_translation).first
    end
end
```

If you are not you could use a virtual attribute:

```
class City
  attr_accessor :_locale 
  attr_accessor :_language
end
```

Which you would have to set in the controller.

```
@boats.port.city._locale = 'fr'
```

And then could use like:

```
class TranslationService
  # ...
    def translateCity(city)
        city.translations.where(locale: city._locale).pluck(:element_translation).first
    end
end
```

But it's a bit hacky.

I would use [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to create the json as @devkaoru recommended. [jBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) is also an alternative, but its kind of a PITA to test (its DHH's pet so it gets included in Rails).

```
class BoatSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :name
   has_one :port
end

class PortSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :name
   has_one :city
end

class ProvinceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :name
end

class CitySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :translated_name
  belongs_to :province

  def translated_name
    TranslationService.translateCity(object)
  end
end

render :json => @boats, each_serializer: BoatSerializer
```

This may seem like a bunch of bloat - but its much better that repeating JSON serialisation all over your controller methods.

Comment: I know you have already answered your own question but I was already 3/4 done with this answer and I still think it has some merit over your solution.

Comment: No problem, the right answer is for you :). Although I was looking for the answer with my solution. Maybe you can help me a bit more. I have realized I need to pass the language parameter (coming in the request to the controller) to the translatedCity method in the model.

Comment: Edited with example using AR serializers and how to provide the locale to the translation service.

Comment: I wish always got answers like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it with:

```
render :json => @boats, :include => {:port => {:only => [:id, :name], :include => {:city => {:only => [:id, :name], :include => {:province => {:only => [:id, :name]}}}}, :methods => :translatedCity},
```

Comment: There are also methods like `as_json` that would have helped you in your case. I would also consider using something like `ActiveRecord::Serializer` (https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) so your controllers don't become bloated with deep hashes.